JWT token not getting removed from the cookie
I am implementing authentication system using jsonwebtoken and bcryptjs. For backend I am using Nojes + Typescript + Mongodb and for the frontend I am using Nexjs 14. I am basically generating a token a storing it into the cookie when the user is trying to log in. Here you can see my login api.
export const loginUser = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, LoginUser>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (!email || !password) {
      return next(
        new MyErrorClass("Please enter all the required fields", 404)
      );
    }

    const user = await userModel.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
      return next(new MyErrorClass("No user found", 404));
    }

    const hasshedPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!hasshedPassword) {
      return next(new MyErrorClass("Invalid Email or password", 401));
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        _id: user._id,
      },
      process.env.SECRET_KEY!
    );
    
    return res
      .status(200)
      .cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 90days
      })
      .json({
        success: true,
        message: `Welcome back ${user.email}`,
      });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return next(new MyErrorClass(error.message, 500));
  }
};

Now when in the logout api i am simply putting an empty string in the cookie.
Logout api
export const logoutUser = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    return res
      .status(200)
      .cookie("token", {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: true,
        expires: new Date(0),
        path: "/"
      })
      .json({
        success: true,
        message: `User logged out successfully`,
      });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return next(new MyErrorClass(error.message, 500));
  }
};

In the frontend I am getting the message from the server that I have been logged out but the cookie is still there.
I have tried every possible changes that can be made into my api, but still not working. How can I remove the token from my cookie?
